# How to say sum of complex number is non zero

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\omega$ be primitive nineth root of unity. Let $a= \omega^4+\omega^3+\omega^2-\omega-2$.
Is there a nice way to show the sum is non zero?

Given some linear combination of powers of primitive $n$-th roots of unity with coefficient from real, Is there a nice way to show whether it is 0 or not?

(One may also assume the coefficients are integers, and maximum power of primitive $n$-th that comes in linear combination $\leq \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor.)$

Comment: Since $\varphi(n)\le\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$ for lots of $n$, there will be many ways to get $0$ under your conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The degree of the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over the rationals is $\phi(9)=6$.

In general, for any $f\in\Bbb{Z}[X]$ one has $f(\zeta_n)=0$ if and only if $f$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$, which is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: Your idea is nice by justifying that is nonzero by the  degree four of the expression because it is less than the degree of minimal polynomial, but isn't the degree of minimal polynomial for the ninth root of unity equal nine ?

Comment: Can you suggest reference for me to learn more about how to know the degree of minimal polynomial and how is it related to Euler phi function?

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar The minimal polynomial for the primitive root is the cyclotomic polynomial. So you may want to read about that.

Comment: @AnuragA   Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: And I want to thank you, the answerer, for giving more details.

Answer (score 5):

Since
$$\omega^4+\omega^3+\omega^2-\omega-2=(\omega-1)(\omega+1)(\omega^2+\omega+2),$$
it is enough to show that $\omega^2+\omega+2\neq0$. Since $\cos(\tfrac{2\pi k}{9})>0$ for $k=1,2,$ we are done.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you can bound the real part of $a$ away from zero by looking at individual terms:

- the real parts of the terms $\omega^4, \omega^3, -\omega$ are obviously negative, by considering their arguments $8\pi/9, 2\pi/3, 11\pi/9$
- the real part of $\omega^2$ is less than $+1$;
- the real part of $-2$ is $-2$

So $Re(a) < 0 + 1 - 2 = -1$ and thus $a \not = 0$.